# PowerApps responsive layouts

Tags: mobile, containers, powerapps, screen-size, flutter-responsive-layout

We have developed a PowerApps application that works well for websites. Now, we are looking to create a similar application for mobile devices. Instead of building two separate PowerApps applications for website and mobile, we are exploring the idea of modernizing the existing application to make it responsive.

We've attempted to achieve this using containers, but it's proven to be quite time-consuming and hasn't resulted in an exact match to the website layout. We've also experimented with screen and parent dimensions but haven't been successful in achieving a fully responsive layout.

Could anyone provide suggestions on different ways to modernize our existing web PowerApps application to make it responsive and compatible for mobile devices?

Comment: Why would you post same text twice? Please don't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below for building responsive Power Apps canvas applications:

- Responsive layouts/screens
- Containers (Horizontal container/Vertical container)
- Formulas for dynamic layout

Refer below Microsoft official documentation for building responsive Power Apps canvas applications:

1. [Building responsive canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/build-responsive-apps)
2. [Create responsive layouts in canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/create-responsive-layout)